# In angularjs, how to bind a label that contains html to a button

Tags: angularjs

I have a button whose label changes based on the email address in the input. If it's "bob@example.com" the button says "Auto Login", other wise just say "Login"

```
<input ng-model="user.email" id="email" />
<button id="login" data-ng-focus data-ng-model="user.loginSubmit">{{user.email === "bob@example.com" ? "<em>Auto</em> Login" : "Login"}}</button>
```

When I remove the  html around the 'Auto' the button works fine, otherwise angular doesn't render anything

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz4e07ag/)

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you can not use Html strings in side expressions directly. You have to use ng-bind-html or ng-bind-html-unsafe directives.

You can use ng-show/ng-hide

```
<span ng-show="user.email === 'bob@example.com'"><em>Auto</em></span>Login</button>
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz4e07ag/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Inline Angular expressions and `ng-bind` do not allow HTML inside. I suggest to replace inline text binding with [`ng-bind-html`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml) directive:

```
<button
    id="login"
    data-ng-focus
    ng-model="user.loginSubmit"
    ng-bind-html="user.email === 'bob@example.com' ? '<em>Auto</em> Login' : 'Login'"
></button>
```

[`ng-bind-html`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml) has dependency on [ngSanitize](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ngSanitize), so you'll have to add it too:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'my.controllers',
    'ngSanitize'
]);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz4e07ag/2/).

Comment: ngSanitize isn't an option here, otherwise this would be the best solution, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I like Anand's answer more too.